# Controlled clinical trial, what is controlled refering to?

Tags: biostatistics

We say a (randomized) **controlled** clinical trial for a specific study design. Now my question is, what is **controlled** refering to?

Different things come up to my mind:

- Controlled in the sense that the design and the process of the study
  is fixed before the study begins, so before the data is genereated
  i.e. before the patients receive the treatment
- controlled in the sense that in a controlled clinical trial you
  always have a control group, in opposite to most observational studies,
  where there not necessarily a control group (in a case-control-study
  you do have a control group and this is also a observational study)
- controlled in the sense that you control for unobserved confounders

Answer (score 3):

The phrase is usually given the second meaning you list, that there is a control group to compare with the treated group. Ideally, the study is randomized, so the assignment of each individual to control or treatment is determined randomly. The idea here is your third meaning, to control for unexpected confounders.

Comment: To just encourage some discussion: confounding for *what* exactly? Selection of treatment? Duration or compliance with  treatment? When an RCT inspects a drug that has never before been released, then nobody has taken that drug so is there even a concept of confounding at this point?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that it can be pointing to the randomisation because RCT (randomised controlled trial) would then be a tautology. It must allude to the 'control' group. I'm sure the society for clinical trials could provide the answer. Interestingly, they changed their journal from 'controlled clinical trials' to simply 'clinical trials' when they switched publisher

Comment: +1. However, controlling of unexpected cofounders can be not only by randomization or blindness.

Comment: You can have head-to-head comparisons so I am not sure the control group is necessary.